# Windows IOT core send recieve data to “umwatson.trafficmanager.net”

Tags: uwp, iot, windows-10-iot-core

I wrote a program to transfer data from a Windows IOT core device to my server via 4G router (a sim card in it). at first I find the network costs nearly 10m per day, which is far more than I send. I close some services including autoupdate service, push message service, and the network costs reduce to 400+k a day. But I still can see the IOT device send receive data from "umwatson.traffic.net", some data packages are nearly 5000 bytes long. My question is what that site is for, and how can I set the system to avoid send receive data from that address?

[image: Message analyzer screen shot]

Comment: It seems Azure service related for me. I'll consult the related engineer.

Comment: You might consider modifying the hosts file to redirect the unwanted traffic to 127.0.0.1